# Batch script failing at 7z command

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b
set TODAY=%year%
echo %TODAY%
7z a D:\Catalog_Bkp\BKP_%TODAY%.7z D:\Catalog_Backup
pause
exit
```

When i run this script it is failing at 7z telling that 7z is not recognized as internal or external command but same command wrote in command prompt it is working fine.

```
7z a D:\Catalog_Bkp\Backup_%DATE:~7,2%.7z D:\Catalog_Backup
```

Comment: Provide full path to `7z` as follows: `"full_path_to_7z\7z" a D:\Catalog_Bkp\Backup_%DATE:~7,2%.7z D:\Catalog_Backup`

Comment: You should not parse each portion of the date using 3 individual `date /T` outputs; remember that these are three independent values then. Rather parse the date with a single `for /F` loop. Concerning the essential problem: where do you start your script and also the manually typed command line from? is the containing directory of `7z` part of the system's `PATH` variable?

Comment: It worked after adding full path. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely you've placed your 7z.exe in the same folder as your script; if so, try this:

```
%~dp07z a filename.7z
```

The `%~dp0` tells the script to look for 7z.exe in the same folder as the *script*, as opposed to in the current working directory.